# Bot to automatically reverse GitHub pull request merges

Tags: git, github, automation, bots

I'm wondering if there's a manageable way to have a bot that detects any 'merge pull request' (button) actions on a GitHub repository and immediately force pushes back to GitHub to make it seem like they never happened?

While using git flow, we manually merge squash pull requests in order to keep a very clean mainline in our project. However it's simply too easy to click that "Merge Pull Request" button by accident and once or twice a month someone does it. We reverse that action by doing a force push so that it "never happened" in our history, but the longer  the time between the accidental merge and someone fixing it, the higher chance that someone else pulls from the repository and later has a mess on their hands. So.. is there any existing solution or almost-existing solution where we can have a bot running somewhere like Heroku that can achieve this? Obviously 99.999% uptime is not necessary as our fallback would just be the current manual steps we take.

Comment: How is the bot supposed to differentiate between accidental and intentional merges?

Comment: Any clicking of the GitHub "Merge Pull Request" button is accidental. i.e. any act of using GitHub's built-in "merge pull request" functionality should be reversed. We merge branches manually instead.

Comment: So, I presume there is some standard text in the merge commit's message. Is this true?

Comment: They all seem to start with 'Merge pull request #' message. But it's a messed up history as they deliberately do a `-no-ff-merge` even if it's possible. I had been assuming that any solution would do it via the GitHub API and not via scraping git commit messages though.

Comment: This would probably involve some type of hook that restricts commits with that message.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's best to not allow the merges instead of reverting them.

- [protect your branch(es)](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-protected-branches/)
- [Enabling required status checks](https://help.github.com/articles/enabling-required-status-checks/)

  - Select **Require status checks to pass before merging**
  - choose (create) a status check, that always fails